# UIView is a child of UIScrollview, but when I zoom in or out the UIView doesn't stay in the correct location relative to the image in the scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

The scrollview shows a floorplan, and the UIView is a little green dot that shows the user's location on the floorplan. So I need to be able to zoom in, and have the green dot stay in the same spot on the floorplan. When I pan, the green dot moves correctly, but when I zoom, it moves away from where it should be.

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard. The small green square is the view that is a child of the Scrollview, and shows the user's location. I move it around programatically, but this is not causing the problem.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvD8I.png

Heres the code that puts the tilemap into the scrollview:

```
CCDirector* director = (CCDirector *)[self childViewControllers][0];
director.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, floorplanWidth, floorplanHeight);
CGSize sizeOfScene = CGSizeMake(floorplanWidth, floorplanHeight);
float minimumScale = 1;//This is the minimum scale, set it to whatever you want. 1.0 = default
_sceneScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
_sceneScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;
_sceneScrollView.zoomScale = .1;
[_sceneScrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[_sceneScrollView sizeToFit];
[_sceneScrollView setContentSize:sizeOfScene];
[_sceneScrollView addSubview:[director view]];
```

Comment: can u put up a screenshot of your storyboard to show the view hierarchy?

Comment: you say it's all done in storyboard then you say you move it programmatically and its not causing the problem... so confusing... what function are you calling to zoom / pan?  what are the frame coordinates of your green dot?  how do these coordinates change as you zoom/pan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a lot of things wrong with what I see above that leads me to believe that you should probably look up more information regarding iOS and scrollviews. The first thing is that a scrollView has a contentSize that's either intrinsically determined via auto layout, or via code by setting the contentSize. In this case, your contentSize would be set via setting the image. The second thing to note is when you zoom in using a scrollView, you provide a view to zoom in on. This view and it's respective subviews will be zoomed in on. I see that your green dot is in the storyboard and is a direct subview inside the scrollview's contentView, this is incorrect. Your green dot will need to be either a subview of your own containerView with the UIImageView and your dot in it, or a subview of your UIImageView (which is sometimes wanky in the storyboard, you'll you'll want to add that in code). To note, UIImageViews have their own scale factor inside of them versus iOS's scale factor. So if you're attempting to dynamically mark anything in a UIImageView, keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it makes sense. And yea I'm pretty new to this. It's extra confusing because the content inside the scrollview is actually a tilemap, and it's kind of hard to reference. I have one question about what you wrote: Can you clarify this sentence a little? " Your green dot will need to be either a subview of your own containerView with the UIImageView and your dot in it, or a subview of your UIImageView". I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: I added some code to the question to help. So it seems I need to make the green dot a subview of this tileview?